# Global IP in Android devices?

Tags: networking, internet, android, webserver

I wanted to host a small website using my Android device and also using its own carrier data and not wifi. I installed an application called Server for PHP from the play store and the server worked fine.

Now, I found that there is an IP address for the device which you can find in settings. As long as I've had this device, that IP hadn't changed. Now I just typed the IP onto a device not connected to my phone via any possible local network and voila, the web page was displayed perfectly.

So yes, I want to know what is going on here? Static IPs for Android devices? Plus, is there something similar for your regular laptops or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile carriers typically use one of two systems for Internet connectivity from the cell network. Those systems are:

- Mobile IP
- Carrier-grade NAT

When Mobile IP is used this generally means you will have an Internet routable IP address with the ability to receive incoming connections. While Carrier-grade NAT IP addresses are shared and translated. Outgoing connections establish mapped ports back to your "shared use" IP so that applications like http work but are not Internet routable. It may provide a static IP though but doesn't always give guarantees about that even while connected your IP might change but in either case there's no way to make a connection to the IP behind the NAT.

In most cases this means using an IP tunnel from the subnet that you're currently connected to what is called the "home node." This is thought of as the network that is default for each user. However in implementation this is fairly arbitrary its just what ever server your carrier assigns you. It may even change from day to day. (hints would not be the same IP).

But this implementation lends itself to non changing IPs. Each time your device connects to the Internet it shouldn't change IP per the spec but there is no real reason to intentionally change it either. This gives you the characteristic of a static IP. But the carrier doesn't actually make any guarantees it will stay the same from connection to connection.

Comment: P.S. Whom ever your cell carrier is give them a pat on the back for supporting Mobile IP.